# Remove port number from URL with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: apache, nginx, apache2, nginx-reverse-proxy

What can I do if I have the following problem:

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, I have an Apache webserver, using Nginx as reverse proxy for it

My Apache webserver is running correctly under the url of *dev.something.com:44999*, using the following configurations in */etc/apache2/sites-available/dev_something_com.conf*:

```
<VirtualHost *:44999>

    ServerName dev.something.com:44999

    ServerAdmin something@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev_something_com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The */etc/apache2/ports.conf* file has been changed to listen to 44999 too.

However, I would like to change it from *dev.something.com:44999* to *dev.something.com*, removing its port number from its url.

The Nginx file looks like this in */etc/nginx/sites-available/default*:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://dev.something.com:44999;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

As you can see here, its listening to port 80, and have the proxy_pass command pointing to the correct url, but it still doesn't work on *dev.something.com*, only with *dev.something.com:44999*.

Please note, that I have a legitimate domain instead of "something", with a correct DNS configuration, so it is not local. Could you please help me out how can I fix this problem?

I would really, highly appreciate it! Thanks for the answers in advance! :)

Comment: 1) Why is Nginx proxying for Apache2? Just configure Nginx correctly to serve the site. 2) Apache listens on all network interfaces, exposing Apache to the public Internet. 3) The `proxy_pass` statement uses an FQDN. Instead, it should use localhost. 4) The reason the port number is displayed is due to item #3. The client is bypassing Nginx.

Comment: @JohnHanley Unfortunately changing the qualified domain to localhost in proxy_pass statement didn’t help at all.

Comment: You have multiple problems with your configuration and unanswered details.

Comment: @JohnHanley  Thank you for highlighting these things, with all due respect and due to my newcomerness, could you please specify what details are unanswered and what are those multiple problems so I can collaborate? :)